# CSS shadow, Can I put a percent unit?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make animated buttons using only CSS. I use pseudo elements before and after and box-shadow element.

Here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fbohd7ko/

The problem is the box-shadow don't accept percent units, and I have to use pixels, but if I want to make this effect an universal effect I can't with pixels. See the jsfiddle, I calculate the box-shadow to fit on the first button, but the on next one the border don't fit correctly.

Can I do something like: `box-shadow:-100% 0 #fff`?

Thanks! (And sorry for my English)

Comment: Apparently no, you can't: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow

Comment: first understand box shadow , go thru https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow & https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Tools/Box-shadow_generator

Comment: @G.L.P And what I should do to make this effect an universal effect? (I mean, the width of the button shouldn't afect)

Comment: The answer to your question is no, making every answer so far unnecessary. Are you wanting to know how to accomplish the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the effect you want to generate

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  background: steelblue;
}
.item {
  position: relative;
  background: #336084;
  padding: 8px 30px;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.from-right:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 3px;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  transition: all .3s;
  opacity: 0;
}
.from-right:hover::before {
  opacity: 1;
  left: 0;
}

.from-left:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 3px;
  top: 0;
  right: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  transition: all .3s;
  opacity: 0;
}
.from-left:hover::before {
  opacity: 1;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="item from-right">From Right</div>
<div class="item from-right">From Right Largest text</div>

<div class="item from-left">From Left</div>
<div class="item from-left">From Left Largest text</div>
```

Comment: What about this? http://jsfiddle.net/62bbrcdr/ Here I need to use box-shadow to create another border effect. There is an alternative to box-shadow? Thanks again!

Comment: You are amazing! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of changing `boxshadow` value in `%,` you can change the `left and right values in %`. Asfar I tried like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fbohd7ko/2/)** Just to show how you can start with..

```
.border-from-right::before {
    content: "";
    display:block;
    background:#336084; 
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    left:100%;
    transition:all .3s;
    width:3px;
    box-shadow:3px 0 #336084;    

}

.border-from-right:hover::before {
    box-shadow:3px 0 #fff;  
    left:0px; 
}
```

And you cant use box shadow values in %. For more info refer this **[Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow)**.. Hope this helped you :)

Comment: What about this? http://jsfiddle.net/62bbrcdr/ Here I need to use box-shadow to create another border effect. There is an alternative to box-shadow? Thanks!